# having trouble with broadband modem connection in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: tag

having trouble with broadband modem connection in Ubuntu 15.10 it will sometimes recognize and connect for some minutes and stop, while sometimes it does not even connect.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run the `dhclient` command under root. If that does not work try running `ifconfig`. It may also be a problem with your network card, this command will show you your network cards `ip link show`.
Here is what output will look like:

```
 $ 1: lo:  mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I tried the command dhclient it shows RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Comment: So did I answer your question? If I did make sure to press the check icon.

Comment: **OFF TOPIC** I am creating a project and I would like you to support it. [Click here to support](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94808/poke-m-e-cms?referrer=ay5l_EV31XrKJk1G61wGvQ2)